# Is there a Plug and Play demonstration kit for various types of attacks?

Tags: metasploit

I'm going to lecture a group of students about Information Security. I'm going to explain the theoretical sides of SQLi, Buffer Overflow and XSS.

I wanted to give them a live demonstration without breaking the law. Do you happen to know of any framework (maybe even Metasploit is capable of this) that has various of vulnerable services and programs which I can demonstrate the attacks on?

Comment: While there are tools and demos out there, we generally discourage temporal questions because their answers would likely change over time and/or only be useful to a specific time.

Comment: @MatthewPeters I feel you, can you help me generalize the question, so you or others will be able to help me?

Comment: The premise of your question might be salvaged `how can I demo exploits without breaking the law` but even that is *too* general. You would need to elaborate on *what* exploits you are looking to demonstrate and what you have already put together... although, personally, even that may be too lozalised a question...

Comment: Seeing accepted answer + specificity/temporal/product comments, I'm learning / trying to comment in the right spirit. For tools like Metasploit (in the question) or famous/important vulnerabilities, often people will develop just what you ask. These training opportunities land on stable sites like SourceForge (Metasploitable) or github, and I was recently shown VulnHub (prepared VM's + walkthroughs). All subject to change, they can be found in the first place with creative Google Alerts (CVE, vulnerable/exploitable VM, etc). Updates to security trainers regularly surface with the news.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are deliberately vulnerable web applications available from several sources, these can be downloaded and run locally and have been created for the type of activity you describe.

The [OWASP WebGoat Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebGoat_Project) is one such example, which has been around a while and can be effectively used on a single machine to demo the principles of web app vulnerabilities.

As a side note, Metasploit is a different beast and is good for demo'ing things like exploiting remote privilege escalation vulnerabilities, and while it can be used on a single machine (with multiple VMs) I find it is more effective with at least two separate machines (one of which will have to have vulnerable software running on it).

Comment: I cringe every time someone answers a question with a specific product/site; it's the classic [prisoner's dilemma](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/prisoners-dilemma.asp) where SX is trying to eliminate product/service recommendation questions... The second half of your answer, is valid but should just be a comment instead.

Comment: All I have is one machine with VMs on it so I guess I'll go for the first option to demonstrate how can shellcode be executed using buffer overflow.

Comment: @MatthewPeters while I would normally concur, on this occasion I think that since OWASP is a not for profit organisation that exists to improve software security and that the WebGoat project is specifically intended for teaching web application security, I think it would be remiss not to make the OP aware of it. By all means 'shoot me at dawn' if ever I recommend a commercial product for something, but on this occasion I think the cringe is misplaced.

Comment: ha, I hear you R15 and I mean no disrespect. It's just that it doesnt seem the OP did much [due diligence](http://google.com) before asking. Maybe I'm too harsh/strict on question quality, you know it doesnt seem like we have a solid standard to go by; well, that's a meta.security question...

Comment: @R15 You could edit your question to generalize what WebGoat is and then specifically call out WebGoat as a current example.

Comment: @MatthewPeters woha, I have to be an expert in asking questions in order to ask the experts a question? I had a running TomCat server with WebGoat before R15's answer.

Comment: @schroeder One can simply browse OWASP's website to get an understanding of what WebGoat is. I was actually looking for WebGoat or other tools, but w/e.

Comment: @Quaker I think schroeder's comment was directed at me (question should have read answer) so that it fits the guidelines better and helps prevent the question being modded into oblivion. Also MatthewPeters comment(s) are reasonable in the context of some of the questions that are asked here, on the flip side while your question does not demonstrate mush research, I looked at your profile and your activity across other sites in SX persuaded me a quick answer was justified.